# Why is my code not building on Xcode without any red lines?

Tags: c++, xcode

This is my first post on here and I am also new to C++ and I was assigned a few problems and they include:
A person’s age is greater then and equal to 18 and the person is taller than 5 feet.
And I am stuck on the first question and I added what I have currently.
I have more questions but I would appreciate any help, tips or anything leading me in the right direction. Thank you very much.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int personAge = 0;
int personHeight = 0;
int feet, inches;
cout << "What is your age and how tall are you in feet without inches?\n";
if ((personAge <= 18 ) && (personHeight <= 5)) {cout << "Nice"; }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so something is wrong with your build environment or something.

Comment: Any recommendations, I am dealing with the same problem on another project, finished it and when i build it it says error and when I click the red X it sends me to another project of mine which i closed a few hours ago.